# Drag-and-drop Sortable List in Meteor

Tags: meteor, jquery-ui-sortable, collaboration

How would you make this?

The items in the list could correspond to records in a collection, and their position in the list could correspond to a field on each record ("rank" perhaps) which would have to be updated when the 'stop' event occurred.

Would Meteor play nicely with jQueryUI Sortable?  What would happen if multiple users attempted to drag and sort the same list at once?  Would Meteor need a customized sorting behavior?

Comment: I think you could implement it fairly easily. You would create your list-data through typical Meteor templates, and then use the `Template.name.rendered()` callback to apply `$().sortable()`. You could then setup the event handlers in the same place, which could update the Collection when called.

Comment: in case people don't read all the answers, as of 0.9.0 sortable list with .sortable works just fine.  they have an example on their repo here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/unfinished/reorderable-list

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: The below answer is out of date, @cutemachine's answer or  http://blog.differential.com/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui is much closer to the state of the art.

---

The short answer is: this isn't easy if you want it to be reactive.  To make a non-reactive version, just wrap your template in a `{{#constant}}` tag and hook up the jquery-ui sortable in `render` as @bento suggested.

To make a reactive version, your sortable widget is going to have to deal with things changing under it (think about being mid-drag when data re-orders itself). Here are some thoughts about how you would go about it:

1. Unfortunately, it's not going be easy to make it animate, which is going to lead to poor UX. Let's leave that aside for now.
2. Render the items with something like:
   `{{#each items}}
   {{> item}}
   {{/item}}`

   This will re-order itself when data comes down from the server (without animation).
3. Set up each item to be draggable when it renders. You could either

   i. Use something like jquery-ui draggable, and hook it up in `render` on the `item` template. You might have problems doing this as the underlying element may disappear during a drag if the ordering changes from upstream.

   ii. implement your own dragging code, perhaps using a lower level library.
4. When an item is dragged into position, immediately reorder the list locally (that way the user should see the right thing. Hopefully the server will respect the change.. but let's not get into that either).

I think there is a big need for such a widget, done in a meteoric way. It's on my personal radar (but so are a lot of things, including a nice way to re-order with animation).

Comment: It appears that wrapping an {{#each}} with a {{#constant}} has no effect, and allowing jquery sortable to modify the dom causes meteor to delete nodes or enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Even if constant did work, I'd need some way to add/remove items in the list, which I guess I'd have to implement manually?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. This is why I'm not a huge fan of the `{{#constant}}` approach. You _could_ do it with an `observe` however.

Comment: Well, tell me when an official implementation appears

Comment: Good luck with this @TomColeman, I think finding solutions for scenarios like this would be amazing considering how much programmers could get for free out of Meteor.  I'm thinking perhaps a way to "pause" reactivity in a limited scope would be very cool.  On "Start Drag" you could pause reactivity on the list, locking it for other clients.  On "Drop" you could update the underlying data and resume reactivity.  You could still track the dragged object's location and report it to other clients.  They'd be locked so reactivity would be safe for them.  Heh, looking back this sounds a bit crazy.

Comment: @Milimetric That seems like an unnecessarily large lock to hold, especially in an evented runtime. I think it would be better to just disable dropping during invalidation/recalculation. The user could be alerted via UI like 'disabling' (greying out) the dragged element and/or drop target.

Comment: +1 to locking reactivity, what happens is that the dragging is cancelled mid drag, which is confusing. drags are short timewise..

Comment: Hey Tom, maybe hide this answer now in the Blaze era? Or update to http://differential.com/blog/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score 5):

Meteor's new rendering engine Blaze now plays with jQuery much more nicely. [Here is short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISNEhPG0wnA) which shows how to implement a sortable list with Meteor and jQuery-UI-sortable.

The [code can be found in the Meteor repository on GitHub in the example folder](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/unfinished/reorderable-list).

Comment: This [example no longer works due to API changes](http://differential.com/blog/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui).

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for 1.0

Check out MeteorPad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/TzQTngcy7PivnCCjk/sortable%20demo

Here is the version I implemented - very similar to @tomsabin's, but no Collection Behaviors needed. It has worked well for me with multiple users and is reactive.

**HTML**
(Probably not a good idea to make the div id the same as _id, I'm sure you'll find a better workaround.)

```
<template name="myList">
  <div class="step_list">
    {{#each card}}
      {{> card_template}}          
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="card_template">
  <div class="card" id="{{_id}}">             
       <h3>{{name}}</h3>   
  </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.myList.helpers ({
    card : function () {
        return Cards.find({}, {sort: {pos: 1}}
    )}
})

Template.myList.rendered = function(){

     $(".step_list").sortable({
       items: ".card",
       delay: 100,
       refreshPositions: true,
       revert: true,
       helper: "clone",
       scroll: true,
       scrollSensitivity: 50,
       scrollSpeed: 35,
       start: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass("dragging");
       }, // end of start
       stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).removeClass("dragging");
       }, // end of stop
       update: function(event, ui) {
        var index = 0;                   
        _.each($(".card"), function(item) {
          Cards.update({_id: item.id}, {
            $set:{
              pos: index++,
            }
          });
        });
      } 
    }).disableSelection();

}
```

Comment: Can you confirm this works after the [API changes](http://differential.com/blog/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui)? Maybe make a Meteorpad for it?

Comment: It still works, basically. You no longer have you remove the helper. Here is a Meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/TzQTngcy7PivnCCjk/sortable%20demo 
Although I like Blaze.getData approach better. No need to plant the _id of each record in the dom.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent example of sortable lists with Meteor and jQuery UI was posted in October 2014 by Differential:

http://differential.com/blog/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui

Note that previous solutions may not work after Meteor switched to the Blaze templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement a drag and drop, sortable and editable list using [jQuery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and [Meteor Collection Hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) and [contentEditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) respectively. For a partially working example, check out [this demo](http://sortable-editable-drag-n-droppable-lists.meteor.com/).

My implementation is as follows (unfortunately it won't be a simple plug in and go example, <strike>but I hope to get a demo up and running for this specific example soon</strike>):

**Client JS for drag, drop and save:**

```
Template.templateName.rendered = ->
  Deps.autorun ->
    $('#list').sortable
      handle: '.handle'
      stop: (event, ui) ->
        _.each $(event.target).children('div'), (element, index, list) ->
          Elements.update { _id: element.getAttribute('data-element-id') },
            $set: position: index + 1
```

Few things to notice here, I am using a 'handle' to drag the element around, as inside each div there are other buttons and editable content. Once the user has dragged an element and dropped it in place, the 'stop' event kicks off and I update **every** element in that list with the new positioning.

I also have the ability to add elements to the page, which will be positioned at the bottom of the list. Otherwise you could probably get away with using the [Meteor Collection Behaviours](https://github.com/Sewdn/meteor-collection-behaviours) and/or [Mongo Counter](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-mongo-counter) packages. However, I utilised [Meteor Collection Hooks#.before.insert](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#beforeinsertuserid-doc) as follows:

**Collection before hook**

```
@Elements.before.insert (userId, doc) ->
  highestElement = Elements.findOne({},
                     sort: { position: -1 }
                     limit: 1
                   )
  position = if highestElement? then highestElement.position else 0
  doc.position = position + 1
```

Here we're simply getting the highest document, sorting on the position attribute. If it doesn't exist (e.g. the first element to be created) then we initialise the positions to start at 1.

PS: if you don't understand CoffeeScript, copypasta the code to this [incredible tool (Js2coffee)](http://js2coffee.org/).

Edit: please see a standalone version here: [demo](http://sortable-editable-drag-n-droppable-lists.meteor.com/) (very slow on Meteor's servers) and [source code](https://github.com/tomsabin/meteor-sortable-editable-drag-n-droppable-lists)